# Mounting a SMB Shared Drive to Docker Container

Tags: networking, mount, samba, vpn, docker

I have a SMB shared drive that I am accessing from my Ubuntu OS. I need to connect to a VPN to access this shared drive. The application that I am running through a Docker container needs to access this shared SMB drive. I understand that this should be easily possible using Docker Volume create and I have read the documentation but I am still having trouble. Here is the code that I run to create the volume and run the container. I am able to create the volume without any problems. But the container does not run.

```
   docker volume create \ 
   --driver local \
   --opt type=cifs  \
   --opt device=//IPADDRESS/array/  \ 
   --opt o=username=usr,password=******,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 \
   --name arrayvolume

   docker run -it --rm -v /home/usr/Documents/Research/:/workspace/research \
   -v arrayvolume:/workspace/array --privileged --gpus all -p 8888:8888 imagerun bash
```

When I run the docker run line, I get this error:

```
  docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/array-volume/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount //IPADDRESS/array/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/array-volume/_data, data: username=usrname,password=******,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777: operation not supported.
```

I have tried to find the path to the mounted SMB drive and tried running the code below. But it also returned an error saying "invalid mode" and I think it is because of the colon in the folder name, which I cannot change.

```
  docker run -it --rm -v /home/usr/Documents/Research/:/workspace/research \
  -v /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=IPADDRESS,share=array:/workspace/array \
  --privileged --gpus all -p 8888:8888 -p 8050:8050 imagerun bash
```

I have tried using docker compose but I wasn't sure if it would work if the volume mounting was not working. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Two things. 1. What is the version of Ubuntu you are using? 2. The VPN may not allow what you are trying to do, mine does not.

Comment: 1. Using v22.04, 2. I didn't consider this. I am using a university VPN. I'll contact their support to find out. Is there another way to know?